# mongoDB : Authentication of user is working fine, but getting "Unauthorized not authorized on admin to execute command" in the logs

Tags: mongodb, authentication, admin

I've followed the steps as mentioned in [How do I add an admin user to Mongo in 2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003391/how-do-i-add-an-admin-user-to-mongo-in-2-6)

At first, "auth=true" in the /etc/mongod.conf file is commented out so that authentication is not done and I could create the following users in respective dbs.

Admin:

```
use admin;
db.createUser({user: "mongoRoot", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "root", db: "admin"}]}); 
db.createUser({user: "mongoAdmin", pwd: "password", roles: ["readWrite"]});
db.createUser({user: "siteUserAdmin", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin"}]}); 
db.createUser({user: "mongoDBAdmin", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "dbAdmin", db: "admin"}]}); 
db.createUser({user: "mongoDBOwner", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "dbOwner", db: "admin"}]}); 

db.createUser({user: "mongoWrite", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "readWrite",db: "mongo_database"}]});  (Added in admin so that by giving the command from the command-line 'mongo mongo_database --port 27018 -u mongoWrite -p password --authenticationDatabase admin', the user mongoWrite is able to login as done in https://gist.github.com/tamoyal/10441108)
db.createUser({user: "mongoRead", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "read", db: "mongo_database"}]});  (Added in admin so that by giving the command from the command-line 'mongo mongo_database --port 27018 -u mongoRead -p password --authenticationDatabase admin', the user mongoRead is able to login  as done in https://gist.github.com/tamoyal/10441108)
```

Config:

```
use config;
db.createUser({user: "mongoConfig", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "config"}]});
```

Test:

```
use test;
db.createUser({user: "mongoTest", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "test"}]});
```

mongo_database:

```
use mongo_database;
db.createUser({user: "mongoWrite", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "readWrite",db: "mongo_database"}]}); 
db.createUser({user: "mongoRead", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "read", db: "mongo_database"}]}); 
db.createUser({user: "mongoAdmin", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "mongo_database"}]});
```

After making sure that all the required users are added, turning on the authentication by uncommenting "auth=true" in the /etc/mongod.conf file and restarting the mongodb.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ mongo mongo_database --port 27018 -u mongoWrite -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27018/mongo_database
rs0:PRIMARY> db.test.insert({"Hello":"World"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
rs0:PRIMARY> exit
bye
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ mongo mongo_database --port 27018 -u mongoRead -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27018/mongo_database
rs0:PRIMARY> db.test.insert({"Hello":"World"});
WriteResult({
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 13,
                "errmsg" : "not authorized on mongo_database to execute command { insert: \"test\", documents: [ { _id: ObjectId('559bba6ead81843e121c5ac7'), Hello: \"World\" } ], ordered: true }"
        }
})
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

Everything works fine till this point. The only issue that am encountering is that my log file is getting bombarded with the following 2 lines at almost tens of thousand lines per minute and within no time, my disk is running out of space.

```
2015-07-07T11:40:28.340+0000 [conn3] Unauthorized not authorized on admin to execute command { writebacklisten: ObjectId('55913d82b47aa336e4f971c2') }
2015-07-07T11:40:28.340+0000 [conn2] Unauthorized not authorized on admin to execute command { writebacklisten: ObjectId('55923232e292bbe6ca406e4e') }
```

Just to give an idea, in a span of 10 seconds, 10 MB worth of log file is generated consisting of just the above mentioned 2 lines.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ date
Tue Jul  7 11:44:01 UTC 2015
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvdh       4.8G  388M  4.2G   9% /log
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ date
Tue Jul  7 11:44:14 UTC 2015
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvdh       4.8G  398M  4.2G   9% /log
```

To my knowledge, the authentication seems to be working fine. Just that the logs are getting filled at super sonic speed. What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excessive logging was from the config servers and even after adding the authentication to the config servers with authentication turned on, it wouldn't stop. Upgraded to mongo 3.0.4 for replica sets, turned on the authentication on replica sets and upgraded mongo to 3.0.4 on config servers and it started working fine without any issues (Same steps on mongo 2.6.x would result in the issue I mentioned above). So, we planned to upgrade to 3.0.4 in order to bypass this issue. Hope, it will be helpful to someone.